# Custom View for scroll in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, tableview, customization

I need to create a custom view for scroll the UITableView/ ScrollView.

Here I attached the picture,

[image]

While scroll the color I need to scroll the tableView and up/down arrow button press also the same function.

How can I implement the scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIView` subclass that has controls for moving the page and the scroll bar.

Then you can update the scroll bar from the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Similarly, when the buttons are pressed you can tell the scroll view to `setContentOffset`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How can I implement the scrolling red color view functionality.

Comment: @VineeshTP well you'll be able to get the total height of the content from the scroll view. And you know the height of the scroll view's view. So you can get the percentage of the visible content. This percentage can be used to calculate the height of the red bar in the scroll bar.